# Is it possible to define display data on an object's properties?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

When using the `Format-Table` command, instead of simply listing property names there's an option to provide hash tables containing the property name (or some expression), along with meta data about how that property should be displayed (e.g. `align`, `width`).

```
$InputObject | Format-Table -Property @{Expression='Property1'; Width=100; Align="right";}, @{Expression='Property2'; Width=100; Align="left";}
```

Is there any way to provide this information in the input object's definition, e.g. somehow adding this information to the `PSStandardMembers` member set.

---

### Additional Info

My specific use case is to be able to have default widths and alignments defined within the `Compare-ObjectProperties` method, to avoid anyone using this function from having to call `Format-Table` with all of this property metadata each time.

```
function Compare-ObjectProperties { 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $InputObject
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $CompareObject
    ) 
    Process {
        $properties = @($InputObject, $CompareObject) | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty, Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object -Unique
        $properties | %{
            [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                PropertyName = $_
                InputObject = $InputObject."$_"
                CompareObject = $CompareObject."$_"
            }
        }
    }
}
Clear-Host
$a = Get-ADUser someone
$b = Get-ADUser sometwo
Compare-ObjectProperties $a $b | 
    Where-Object {$_.InputObject -eq $_.CompareObject} | 
    Format-Table @{Expression='PropertyName'; Width=20;}, @{Expression='InputObject'; Width=100; Align="right";}, @{Expression='CompareObject'; Width=100; Align="left";}
```

Comment: You can use [format definition files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6) to do this.

Comment: Nice one, thanks @boxdog; implementing that's slightly more painful than hoped, but solves the problem.  I found a good tutorial on this here; http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Decorating-Objects#formatps1xml

Comment: Glad to help.  I added my comment as an answer, so it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell uses format definition files ([Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6)) to define the default display of objects.

To implement this in your code, include a type in the returned object by replacing;

```
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    PropertyName = $_
    InputObject = $InputObject."$_"
    CompareObject = $CompareObject."$_"
}
```

with:

```
$result = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    PropertyName = $_
    InputObject = $InputObject."$_"
    CompareObject = $CompareObject."$_"
}
$result.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'JohnLBevan.CompareObjectPropertiesResult')
$result
```

Then create a definition file for the given type / with the appropriate property names & settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>Default</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>JohnLBevan.CompareObjectPropertiesResult</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>20</Width>
                        <Alignment>left</Alignment>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>90</Width>
                        <Alignment>right</Alignment>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Width>90</Width>
                        <Alignment>left</Alignment>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>PropertyName</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>InputObject</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>CompareObject</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Save this file as `YourTypeName.format.ps1xml`.

Finally, import this definition into your script:

```
Update-FormatData -AppendPath '.\JohnLBevan.CompareObjectPropertiesResult.Format.ps1xml'
```

Now when you call your function, the output will be dictated by the information in the definition file.